# POST request and get set actions MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, http-get

I cant seem to figure this one out and I'm sure it is something simple.
Whenever I press my "Update/Save" button, my code goes to my Order class to perform the {get;set}'s. However, it is passing my PhonePrimary field as "null" which causes errors.

Below is the EditOrder.cshtml page

```
       @using (Html.BeginForm())
         {
           <div class="form-group-PhonePrimary">
                <div class="input-group" style="border-right:0px">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" style="text-align: left; border-right: 0px; min-width: 115px">Phone #</span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.order.PhonePrimary, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = "13" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.order.PhonePrimary)
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group" style="padding-left:5px">
            <div class="btnUpdateSave">
                <input type="submit" value="Update/Save" class="btn btn-primary col-md-10" />
            </div>
        </div>
       }
```

Below is the Order class.

```
public class Order
{
        private string _PhonePrimary;
                [DisplayName("Phone Primary")]
        public string PhonePrimary
        {
            get
            {
                //this._PhonePrimary = BeautifyPhoneNumber(this._PhonePrimary);

                return BeautifyPhoneNumber(this._PhonePrimary);
            }
            set
            {
                this._PhonePrimary = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the EditOrderViewModel that is being used in the EditOrder.cshtml page

```
public class EditOrderViewModel
{
    public Order order { get; set; }
    public List<Status> StatusOptions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Notary> Notaries { get; set; }
    public Notary NotaryAssigned { get; set; }
}
```

Below are httpget and httppost in the SchedulingController.cs

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditOrder(int id)
        {
            var model = repositoryScheduling.Order_FindById(id);//returns EditOrderViewModel

            model.NotaryAssigned = repositoryScheduling.Notary_FindAssignedNotary(model.order.Id);

            return View(model);
        }
     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditOrder(EditOrderViewModel orderModel)
        {
            try
            {
                repositoryScheduling.Order_Update(orderModel);
                return RedirectToAction("OrderIndex");
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Here is the Order_FindById function found inside the SchedulingREpository.cs. I'm using Dapper to help with the SQL commands.

```
    public EditOrderViewModel Order_FindById(int id)
    {
        var parameters = new DynamicParameters();

        parameters.Add("@ID", value: id);

        var query = @"long query string that i dont want to put";

        using (var multi = this.db.QueryMultiple(query, parameters))
        {
            EditOrderViewModel editVM = new EditOrderViewModel();
            editVM.order = multi.Read<Order>().SingleOrDefault();
            editVM.StatusOptions = multi.Read<Status>().ToList();
            editVM.Documents = multi.Read<Document>().ToList();
            return editVM;
        }
    }
```

Whenever I switch to using `model.order._PhonePrimary` instead of the one in the code currently (`model.order.PhonePrimary`). I receive no errors, but then my `BeautifyNumber()` never is triggered.

Comment: Have you tried running Fiddler or something similar to see what's being submitted back to the server? If so, is it null from the form, or is it not populating your controller's action parameters?

Comment: If i use the same code as the OP, i get this in the TextView on Fiddler - &order.PhonePrimary=%28883%29+332-9302+  > however, in the Order class my PhonePrimary variable has 'PhonePrimary' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' value=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input

Comment: Is "Order" a property of the model? If so, are you instantiating the Order property before you assign the model to the view? I'll submit an answer with code to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you instantiating the Order property before you assign the model to the view.

For example:

```
public ActionResult EditOrder() {
    var vm = new EditOrderViewModel();
    vm.Order = new Order();
    return View(vm);
}
```

EDIT: Try this in your repo:

```
editVM.order = multi.Read<Order>().SingleOrDefault() ?? new Order();
```

EDIT 2: It could be a model binding issue. You could look into using a custom model binder for your POST action, or you could bypass the need for the Order nested class by referencing PhonePrimary directly in your view model and letting your repo take care of populating and digesting it to an Order entry after POST.

Comment: I am, but in another way (using repositories). I added the Controller code to the OP

Comment: Within your repository, are you letting EF supply the Order property via foreign key (navigation property)?

Comment: I'm using Dapper to handle my repository. (adding repo code to OP now)

Comment: Terribly sorry; I'm not sure why I assumed you were using EF. 

Is it possible that SingleOrDefault is returning null? That's the default value for a reference type. You could try returning a new Order if it's null (see my edit in a sec).

Comment: Nope, that's not the case. In my Order_FindById() , the editVM.order comes back with values for my _PhonePrimary (which looks like 1112223333) and for my PhonePrimary (which looks like (111) 222-3333)

Comment: The next thing I'd check is to make sure the model is binding properly. You may need to look into using a custom model binder on your POST action. Or, you could just have a PhonePrimary property in your view model and process it into an Order entry in your repo instead (bypass the need for a nested class).

Answer (score 0):

So, i'm not exactly sure how this fixes the problem. But it does (for now...still waiting for more errors involving this later ^ _^)

I encapsulated the code inside my `BeautifyPhoneNumber()` function with the

```
if (numberToBeautifuy != null)
{
//code
}
else
{
 return "";
}
```

The completed function is below.

```
    public static String BeautifyPhoneNumber(string numberToBeautify)
    {
        if (numberToBeautify != null)
        {


            //The below gives us capture groups for each 
            //individual piece of the number.
            var regularExpression = new Regex(@"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(x\d*)?");
            //This matches a number that's already been beautified, 
            //so we can guard against beautifying twice.
            var alreadyBeautifulExpression = new Regex(@"(\(\d{3}\)) (\d{3})-(\d{4}) ?(x\d*)?");
            var beautifulNumber = string.Empty;
            var separator = "-";
            var space = " ";
            //This prevents us from accidentally beautifying 
            //something more than once
            //You could also guard against this in your getter using a
            //IsBeautified extension, using the alreadyBeautifulExpression above
            if (alreadyBeautifulExpression.IsMatch(numberToBeautify))
            {
                return numberToBeautify;
            }

            //Trying to protect against invalid input... May be insufficient,
            //Or unnecessary
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numberToBeautify)
                || regularExpression.Matches(numberToBeautify).Count <= 0)
            {
                return beautifulNumber;
            }

            GroupCollection groups = regularExpression.Matches(
                numberToBeautify)[0].Groups;

            //More protection against invalid input
            if (groups.Count <= 3)
            {
                return beautifulNumber;
            }

            //Given "7689131234",
            beautifulNumber += "(" + groups[1] + ")" + space; //gives us "(768) "
            beautifulNumber += groups[2] + separator; //gives us "(768) 913-"
            beautifulNumber += groups[3]; //gives us "(768) 913-1234"
            //If we have an extension, we add it.
            if (groups[4] != null)
            {
                beautifulNumber += space + groups[4];
            }

            return beautifulNumber;
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

If someone can explain to me why this works, that would be great and I will give you 'the answer' points.